# How to create a custom Django template tag working outside of a block?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my project, I need to treat CSS requirements differently depending on several parameters. Thus, I need an additional level of abstraction compared to available static management systems.

In my templates, I would like to be able to register CSS (and JS) requirements with a template tag which would look like `{% register_css 'myfile.css' %}`. This approach works like a charm.

However, there is still one problem with this approach : the tag works perfectly when inserted in a block, but never gets called when inserted on top of a child template. The tag definition is:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def register_css(context, *args):
    context['static_registry'].register_css(streamlet)
    return ''
```

This is my test template:

```
{% extends main_skelton %}
{% load static_registry %}
{% register_css 'base' %}

{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% register_css 'home' %}
<p>Some content here</p>
{% endblock %}
```

In that template, the 'home' css gets registered, but not the 'base' one. How may I make both work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include an empty `{% block init %}` in your base template, then override that block in the child templates to register files - `{% block init %}{{ block.super }} {% register_css 'foo %}{% endblock %}`

The underlying issue is that in a child template, only blocks that match something in the parent template will get rendered. AFAIK there's no easy way around that, but using a dummy block works just fine.

Comment: Not really the most exciting way to do it... But it works. Thanks.